# Linux grep a command outcome into a variable

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell

I want a command output stored in a variable.

A.sh

```
out=$(sqlldr userid=scott/tiger control=emp.ctl l grep "value i want")
echo $out
```

But it is giving me **empty output**.

Comment: Add a $ in front of out

Comment: Do you really have `l grep` instead of `| grep`, or is that a mistake you've introduced creating the question? What is the actual value you're looking for, and is it in standard output or error?

Comment: Sorry it was by mistake

Comment: Done!! :) using 2 variables..

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

`OUT=$(sqlldr userid=scott/tiger control=emp.ctl 2>&1 | grep "value i want" )
echo $OUT`

In this case you also will have the error output, so if something is not working properly, you will know.

Comment: Don't you want the `2>&1` before the pipe, so grep will see things from stderr from the `sqlldr` command?

Comment: Yes Alex, sorry. :)